# Querying the max value of a column in SQLite For Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a database created and filed with data. There is a column where i want to find the biggest value.

This is the method used in my database adapter :

```
public Cursor getBiggestInTheColumn() {
    return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, null,
                    "MAX(price)", null, null, null, null);
}
```

It should work but when i call the method :

```
        cursor = dbadp.getBiggestInTheColumn();
```

I Get a Runtime Error Like This(LogCat) :

> 07-14 12:38:51.852: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: misuse of aggregate function MAX(): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM spendings WHERE MAX(price)

Any ideas? I suspect this is due to the bad query, but this is the best that i can come up with. Other queries are working well.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

If you just want the biggest value then you want the SQL equivalent of:
`SELECT MAX(price) FROM spendings`.

I tend to use `db.rawQuery(String sql, String[] selectionArgs)`, so it would be: `db.rawQuery("SELECT MAX(price) FROM spendings", null)`.

But I think you could do this with `db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String [] {"MAX(price)"}, null, null, null, null, null);`. Though I haven't tested that.

Comment: I tried the 'db.rawQuery("SELECT MAX(price) FROM spendings", null)'   but it just changes the error to  : ERROR/AndroidRuntime(335): Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1. Though i feel is the right way to go. Need to inspect the rawQuery method.

Comment: Are you getting that exception when you try to use the cursor to get the data? If so, it sounds like you need to position the Cursor to the first row before you can get data from it. To do this you can call: `mCursor.moveToFirst()`. Also, this method call returns a boolean, which will be false if there are no results; so you can also use it to guard against that case.

Comment: this comment solved my problem after two hours of trying. MOVE THE CURSOR TO THE FIRST RECORD BEFORE USING IT. people always forget that.

Answer (score 9):

please write the query as `select max(price) as price from table name`.

resulting cursor follow the below statement

```
cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("price"));
```

Comment: I had to add cursor.moveToFirst(); before getting actual value to make it work

Answer (score 8):

Another way to get the column could be to set the query to the max of a particular column, for example:

```
db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, null, "price=(SELECT MAX(price))", null, null, null, null)
```

The cursor that returns will be the highest price row in the database.

Comment: SQLiteException: misuse of aggregate: MAX() (code 1)

Answer (score 4):

```
 public Cursor select(String sql)
{
    try
    {
        Cursor cursor = mDataBase.rawQuery(sql,null);
        return cursor;
    }
    catch (SQLException mSQLException)
    {
        throw mSQLException;
    }
}
and
```

call it like:

```
 Cursor cursor = dal.select("SELECT Max(id) FROM terms"); //where en like '"+name+"%'");
if (cursor != null) {
    cursor.moveToFirst();
   int id= cursor.getInt(0);}
```

Comment: select method is in another class "DAL" and create object from DAL "dal"

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the biggest `INTEGER` value then you can use the following:

```
public int getBiggestInTheColumn() {
    return (int) DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(db, "SELECT MAX(price) FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE, null);
}
```

`DatabaseUtils` is added in Android API 1

> public static long longForQuery (SQLiteDatabase db, 
>                   String query, 
>                   String[] selectionArgs)
>
> Utility method to run the query on the db and return the value in the first column of the first row.

[Android Developers > DatabaseUtils](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#longForQuery(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D))

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue in Android.
And `db.rawQuery(String sql, String[] selectionArgs), so it would be: db.rawQuery("SELECT MAX(price) FROM spendings", null) - throw **Exception**.

I fixed by:

```
db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, null, "price=(SELECT MAX(price) FROM + DATABASE_TABLE + ")", null, null, null, null)
```

The cursor that returns will be the highest price row in the database. It work correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get max value of a column in a TABLE you can use this method

```
    public String getMax( String TABLE_NAME, String column_name) {// use the data type of the column
            database.open();
            Cursor cursor = database.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[]{"MAX(" +column_name + ") AS MAX"}, null, null, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst(); // to move the cursor to first record
            int index = cursor.getColumnIndex("MAX");
            String data = cursor.getString(index);// use the data type of the column or use String itself you can parse it 
            database.close();
            return data;
    }
```

If you want to get entire record containing the max value for the column

```
    public List<Object> getMaxRecord(String TABLE_NAME, String column_name) {
            database.open();
            Cursor cursor = database.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[]{"*"}, column_name + " = " + "(SELECT MAX(" + column_name + ") FROM " + TABLE_NAME + ")", null, null, null, null);
            List<Object> demos = cursorToModel(cursor);
            database.close();
            return demos;
    }
```

note: cursorToModel is a method to get list of records in the cursor satishfying the constraint