# SQLite without NULL

Tags: android, sqlite

I have been trying to get the biggest value of a column. For this I sorted it by DESC so the biggest one comes first, but it turns out that any nulls actually come first for some reason. Therefore I tried to add a WHERE, but it still has nulls in it for some reason and I can't figure out why.

```
 String[] projection = {
            DATAbaseContract.DATAbaseEntry.COLUMN_PRICE,
    };
    String sortOrder =
            DATAbaseContract.DATAbaseEntry.COLUMN_PRICE + " DESC";

    Cursor DATAbaseCursor = DATAbaseDb.query(
            DATAbaseContract.DATAbaseEntry.TABLE_NAME,                     // The table to query
            projection,                               // The columns to return
            ShipsContract.ShipsEntry.COLUMN_PRICE + " IS NOT NULL",                                // The columns for the WHERE clause
            null,                            // The values for the WHERE clause
            null,                                     // don't group the rows
            null,                                     // don't filter by row groups
            sortOrder                                 // The sort order
    );
    if(!DATAbaseCursor.moveToPosition(0)) {return;}
    PriceMaxVal=DATAbaseCursor.getInt(DATAbaseCursor.getColumnIndex(DATAbaseContract.DATAbaseEntry.COLUMN_PRICE));
    PriceMinVal=0;
```

Comment: Please refer to this link : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693439/querying-the-max-value-of-a-column-in-sqlite-for-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693439/querying-the-max-value-of-a-column-in-sqlite-for-android)

Comment: Thanks that works, but I still want to know how to exlude nulls properly.

Comment: You're filtering for the wrong column: `COLUMN_CREW + " IS NOT NULL"` while you're ordering by `COLUMN_PRICE`.

Comment: True. But ever after fixing that it still doesn't work.