# SQL Get max value for every n rows

Tags: sql, sqlite

Say I have a table with two columns: the time and the value. I want to be able to get a table with the max values during every n seconds.

If I want the max value for every 3 seconds, the following table:

```
time    value
1       6
2       1
3       4
4       2
5       5
6       1
7       1
8       3
9       7
```

Should return:

```
time    value
1       6
5       5
9       7
```

These are the rows with the max value for each period of 3 seconds (1-3, 4-6, 7-9).

Is there a way to do this directly with an sql query?

Answer (score 0):

Ref: `https://stackoverflow.com/a/6693606/10240461`

[Querying the max value of a column in SQLite For Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6693606/10240461)

OR

[SQLLITE](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-max/)

If you just want the biggest value then you want the SQL equivalent of: `SELECT MAX(price)` FROM spendings.

I tend to use `db.rawQuery(String sql, String[] selectionArgs)`, so it would be: `db.rawQuery("SELECT MAX(price) FROM spendings", null)`.

But I think you could do this with `db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String [] {"MAX(price)"}, null, null, null, null, null);`. Though I haven't tested that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with SQLite, but would do something like this:

```
SELECT a.time,
    a.value
FROM [your_table] a
JOIN (
  SELECT floor((time-1)/3) AS group_3,
      MAX(value) AS max_value
  FROM [your_table]
  GROUP BY 1
  ) b
ON floor((a.time-1)/3) = b.group_3
AND a.value = b.max_value
```

I don't know what the expected outcome should be when 2 times in the same group have the same max value.

Comment: sqlite3 doesn't have the floor function yet.

Comment: Just cast to integer.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this using a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id = (select t2.id
              from t t2
              where floor( (t.id - 1) / 3) = floor( (t2.id - 1) / 3)
              order by value desc
              limit 1
             );
```

Comment: I don't get the reference to t2?

Comment: @gregory . . . That is a second reference to your table.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.time, a.value
FROM table a
JOIN (
  SELECT cast((time-1)/3 as int) AS grouping,
      MAX(value) AS max_value
  FROM table
  GROUP BY 1
  ) b
ON cast(((a.time-1)/3) as int) = b.grouping
AND a.value = b.max_value
```

output:

```
time|value
1|6
5|5
9|7
```

Note: this only works if time >= 0.

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to assign the `id` values to their appropriate `group` and then use `rank()` in combination with `windowed functions` to create the output.

Try this to get started. Replace `[your_table_name]` with whatever table you're pulling the data from in your post.

```
DECLARE @table TABLE ( 
    time int
    ,value int 
    , group_id int 
    ) 


INSERT INTO @table ( time , value ) 
SELECT time , value 
FROM [your_table_name]

UPDATE t
SET group_id = CEILING(t.id/3.0)
FROM @table as t 




SELECT id , value , group_id
FROM  ( 
            SELECT 
                    id
                ,   value 
                ,   group_id
                ,   rank() OVER (PARTITION BY group_id ORDER BY value DESC) AS r 
            FROM @table ) As x 
    WHERE x.r = 1;
```

Comment: window functions are not supported in sqlite3 yet -- they are due in the next version (v3.25).